# How change the response in HandlerInterceptorAdapter in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, compression, gzip

I have a backend written in Java (SpringBoot) which sends the response to the frontend. I am working with too many data in json, so I decided to compress it using GZIP for a quicker transaction, but I have found several errors in the code, due to I don't know very well how to deal with some classes.

I use the postHandle() method with the code above (which I found in stackoverflow in other question):

```
    @Override
    public void postHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

      ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
      gzip.write(request.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      gzip.close();
    }
```

The problem is that my request has not a getBytes() method, so it couldn't be done.

Any idea of how I can do it? I need to compress every data is send from backend to frontend.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-compress-responses-java

Comment: Don't... nor can you do that in an interceptor, you should use. filter instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, Deinum. That makes us to focus in other way, the right way! You solved our problem. Thank you very much.